# need to copy some contient from one txt file to anther txt file by using batch file

Tags: batch-file

Hi I am new to writing batch files so please help me.
I have a txt file with data as below:

```
\nwe data 
test data and
othere files
resrt 
/* 20170804 */
test data
new line and work
only work 
new test
online
master
/*letest*/
```

I want to copy the data from `/* 20170804 */` to `/*letest*/`. How do I get that data copied to another txt file?

Comment: <add key="SyncVersion" value="20170809" />
    <add key="BuildVersion" value="20170809.01" />
    <add key="SA_Prefix" value="" />
    <add key="SW_Prefix" value="" />
    <add key="ST_Prefix" value="" />
can we copy 20170809 and keep it in one temp variable is it possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, create the logic:

```
for every line in the text file do  
  If the line is the start string, set a flag.   
  If flag is set, print the line.   
  If the string is the stop string, delete the flag.  
continue with next line.
```

then redirect all output of the whole loop to a file.

```
@echo off
setlocal 
set "flag="
(for /f "delims=" %%a in (t.txt) do (
  if "%%a"== "/* 20170804 */" set "flag=yes"
  if defined flag echo %%a
  if "%%a"== "/*letest*/" set "flag="
))>out.txt
```

Note: this works with something like your example. If there are special chars or you want to keep empty lines, more code is necessary.

Comment: Thank you so much this works perfectly for me .. I have added some more specific code in that as per our requirements..

Comment: <add key="SyncVersion" value="20170809" />                                              <add key="BuildVersion" value="20170809.01" />
 can we copy 20170809 and keep it in one temp variable is it possible

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at command line tools like [gawk.exe](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/gawk.htm) or [sed.exe](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/sed.htm) that use regular expressions to search patterns and work on the files.

For example `gawk` using flag to print the lines.

```
gawk "/\/\* 20170804 \*\//{flag=1;next}/\/\*letest\*\//{flag=0}flag" C:\temp\data.txt > C:\temp\out.txt
```

Comment: Thanks for your responce.. could you please help me write simple batch file to to copy some data from one txt to anther txt file but not whole data from - to data.. can we copy like this from one file to anther i do need it for windows..